# BookshelfJS limiting withRelated in FetchAll doesn't work

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, bookshelf.js

I have a `hasMany` to `belongsTo` relation between `boxes` and `box_states`.

I want to grab all my boxes with their latest state, so this is my query:

```
new Box()
    .orderBy('id', 'ASC')
    .fetchAll({
        withRelated: [{
            'states' :  function(qb) {
                qb.limit(1)
                    .orderBy('id', 'DESC');
            }
        }]
    })
    .then(function (boxes) {
        res.json(boxes);
    });
```

This returns all the boxes, but only the last box has one relation; everything has no relation.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this works pretty much as expected. If you debug your solution, you'll see something like this (I'm giving you my example, which has the same relation as yours - one town, many addresses):

`select "addresses".* from "addresses" where "addresses"."town_id" in (1, 2, 3, 4) group by "id" limit 1`

What this does is basically select just ONE(!) related model (`address`) for ALL instances (the `addresses.town_id in (1,2,3,4)` segment).

So basically what you need to do is foreach the main results and go `withRelated` upon each.

```
new Town().fetchAll().then(function(towns) {

    var my_towns_with_only_last_address = [];

    Promise.map(towns.toJSON(), function(town) {
        return new Town({
            id: town.id
        }).fetch({
            withRelated: [{
                'address': function(qb) {
                    qb.limit(1);
                    qb.orderBy('id', 'desc');
                }
            }]
        }).then(function(result) {
            return my_towns_with_only_last_address.push(result.toJSON());               
        });
    }).then(function() {
        res.json(my_towns_with_only_last_address);
    });

});
```

I'm not sure if there are any better options... this works.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this now (newest release of Bookshelf) is to use a Collection. Although `withRelated` is not available in `.fetchAll()`, it is available when using `.fetch()` on a Collection. See http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-fetch